# Jquery Tabs created dynamically with dynamic naming assignments

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I am using the jquery ui tabs to create dynamic tabs on the fly which will start off without any content. From what I can tell my code is building everything and putting it in the proper places, but jquery is not recognizing them as tabs. How would I get it to recognize the new tabs that were created after page load?

The html code:

```
    <div class="main">
    <div>
        <button id="new">button</button>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">View1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">View2</a></li>
            <li id="createView"><a href="null">Create New</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <p>something on this page</p>   
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <div>
                <p>something else on this page</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​
```

the Javascript:

```
//Tabs functionality
    $('#tabs').tabs();

    //Create new view


    var tabNum = 3;

    $('#new').click(function() {

        $('#tabs ul').append('<li>' + '<a href="' + '#tabs-' + tabNum + '">' + 'newitem' + '</a>' + '</li>');
        $('#tabs').append('<div id="' + 'tabs-' + tabNum + '">' + '<div>new</div>' + '</div>');
        var NewViewNum = 'tabs-' + tabNum;
        $(NewViewNum).focus();

        tabNum++;

    });​
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Not recognizing them as tabs"?

Comment: Refer http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery UI Tabs have a `refresh` method you can use [per the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-refresh).

Try calling:

```
$("#tabs").tabs("refresh");
```